# How does Elasticsearch do a term query in the shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I know ES sends term query(match query is in fact terms query) to shards, and merge/filter them afterwards, but how does ES do term query in the shards? How do they know one word belongs to which inverted index and where to retrieve them?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what is an inverted index? If so, it's just built like hash-map where you can use the hash value of the term to find it in the index.